# Silverlight WCF Service only working on local host

Tags: wcf, web-services, silverlight, iis, webservice-client

Apologies for the long post but I want to include as much information as possible. So I've been struggling for days now to get my WCF service to work correctly with my silverlight app. I had originally deployed it and everything was running smoothly.

However After i made an update to one of the methods it has not worked since. I use SVN to store my work and even going back to previous versions of the project and redploying it has not helped. Please can someone assist me :(

If I run my silverlight application through VS2012 it works correctly all calls to the service work as required and retrieve the correct information. However if i trigger the same calls once the silverlight app is deployed I receive 1 of the following errors:

```
 An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.

   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at OrionDashboard.OrionWebService.GetTestDataCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at OrionDashboard.MonthlyOverview.OrionWebService_GetTestDataCompleted(Object sender, GetTestDataCompletedEventArgs e)
   at OrionDashboard.OrionWebService.OrionWebServiceClient.OnGetTestDataCompleted(Object state)
```

Or

```
[Async_ExceptionOccurred] Arguments: Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.51204.0&File=System.dll&Key=Async_ExceptionOccurred   at
```

With the rest of the error corresponding to the onComplete event error of the other error message.

Again this only happens when its deployed to the IIS on the server, And it only started happening after i made the update an redeployed

I've used both WCF Storm and WCF Test Client that was included with VS2012 to test the deployed service over the network and everything is being returned without any issues for all the contracts.

Here is the ServiceReferences.ClinetConfig:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_OrionWebService">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                               maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:53493/OrionWebService.svc" 
                  binding="customBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_OrionWebService"
                  contract="OrionWebService.OrionWebService"
                  name="CustomBinding_OrionWebService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have made no changes to this at all from what was auto generated when i referenced the service project. I thought it may have been this line: "http://localhost:53493/OrionWebService.svc"

because in fiddler i receive the following errors on the crossdomain.xml and the clientaccesspolicy.xml

[Fiddler] The socket connection to localhost failed. 
ErrorCode: 10061. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:53493

however when i changed the xap to a zip file and modified the ServiceReference.ClientConfig to point to the same service address as would work if you wanted to check your service e.g. "http://ServerName/OrionDashboard/OrionWebService.svc" I still get the same error from silverlight and then get a 404 error from the two files.

Here is the web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"
                     targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="OrionDashboard.Web.OrionWebService.customBinding0">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                                   multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <services>
            <service name="OrionDashboard.Web.OrionWebService">
                <endpoint address="" 
                          binding="customBinding" 
                          bindingConfiguration="OrionDashboard.Web.OrionWebService.customBinding0"
                          contract="OrionDashboard.Web.OrionWebService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" 
                          binding="mexHttpBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

As with the ServiceReference, the web.config too was left alone because I dont really understand what most of it means. But I left it as is when I first deployed the silverlight app and as mentioned it worked fine then.

- I don't believe its a DB issue since it runs locally without any issues and the service responds with the correct data from the deployed service as well.
- The service seems to be working fine, no issues reported from either the WCF Test Client or WCF Storm app
- In VS2012 when publishing the wcf service it doesn't separate the service from the client and it doesn't create the crossdomain.xml or clientaccesspolicy.xml so I manually added those after publishing it. Not sure if that could possibly be the cause?

I'm completely lost and every work around I've found so far has not worked for me. Please can someone at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: anyone? Even if its just a link to anther article

Comment: I have the same issue with your, but just like you there were only people who read it but no people went here to comment or answer. It look like WCF service can only run on localhost. It was my nightmare on this issue.